# Iterable for both generic and raw type

Tags: java, generics, iterable, raw-types

Without using generic types I have the following which works fine:

```
public class OC_GuillotinePacker implements Iterable<OC_GuillotinePacker> {
    @Override
    public Iterator<OC_GuillotinePacker> iterator() {
        // code that returns a new Iterator
    }
}
```

Which allows me to loop like this:

```
for (OC_GuillotinePacker gp : packer) {

}
```

I updated my code so I can store objects by it's generic type.
Now it's like:

```
public class OC_GuillotinePacker<T> implements Iterable<OC_GuillotinePacker<T>> {
    @Override
    public Iterator<OC_GuillotinePacker<T>> iterator() {
        // code that returns a new Iterator
    }
}
```

The problem is when I create a new OC_GuillotinePacker like:

```
packer = new OC_GuillotinePacker(0, 0, width, height);
```

Then I can't loop anymore like this:

```
for (OC_GuillotinePacker gp : packer) {

}
```

It gives me a incompatible types warning. Requires is OC_GuillotinePacker<> and found is java.lang.Object.

Is it possible to make it so that both is possible? So a raw for each loop and one with a generic type.

Comment: You must provide a type when instantiating OC_GuillotinePacker (for instance, `new OC_GuillotinePacker<String>`).  In the for-loop, you can always use `OC_GuillotinePacker<?>`.

Comment: I don't always want a type. It's optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you made your `OC_GuillotinePacker` class generic, with type parameter `T`, your declaration became raw.

```
packer = new OC_GuillotinePacker(0, 0, width, height);
```

When you use a raw type, type erasure occurs, such that the `iterator()` method now returns a raw `Iterator`, which returns `Object`s.  An `Object` can't be assigned to a `OC_GuillotinePacker`, hence the error.

When creating your `OC_GuillotinePacker`, supply a type argument or use the diamond operator to infer the type from the `packer` variable declaration.

```
packer = new OC_GuillotinePacker<>(0, 0, width, height);
```

This way, the `iterator()` method will return `OC_GuillotinePacker<YourType>` objects to use in your enhanced `for` loop.

```
for (OC_GuillotinePacker<YourType> gp : packer) {

}
```